# What is the difference between these two python functions?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-2.7, return

I am having trouble understanding some of the short hand notation I am seeing in Python. Would someone be able to explain the difference between these two functions please?
Thank you.

```
def test1():
   first = "David"
   last = "Smith"
   if first and last:
      print last


def test2():
   first = "David"
   last = "Smith"
   print first and last
```

Answer (score 5):

The first function always returns `None` (printing `Smith`) whereas the second one always returns `"Smith"`*

**Quick digression into `and`:**

the python `and` operator returns the first "falsy" value it encounters.  If it doesn't encounter a "falsy" value, then it returns the last value (which is "true-y")  This explains why:

```
"David" and "Smith"
```

always returns `"Smith"`.  Since both are non-empty strings, they are both "true-y" values.

```
"" and "Smith"
```

would return `""` since it is a falsy value.

---

*The original function that OP posted actually looked like:

```
def test2():
   first = "David"
   last = "Smith"
   return first and last
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Sorry I actually meant to write "print" for both functions, not print for one and return for the other. It was a typo. I have corrected the questions above. Are the two functions essentially the same now or not? Thank you.

Comment: @Reno -- They're the same since both `first` and `last` are `true-like` values.  If that wasn't the case -- (e.g. if `first` and `last` were arguments to the function), they could still be different.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the functions `test1()` and `test2()` is that `test1()` explicitly prints the value of `last` so long as the result of the expression `first and last` evaluates as true, and `test2()` prints the result of the expression `first and last`.  The string that is printed is the same because the result of the expression `first and last` is the value of `last` - but only because `first` evaluates as true.

In Python, if the left-hand side of an `and` expression evaluates as true, the result of the expression is right-hand side of that expression.  Because of short-circuiting of boolean operators, if the left-hand-side of an `and` expression evaluates as false, the left-hand side of the expression is returned.

`or` also short-circuits in Python, returning the value of the leftmost part of the expression that determines the entire expression's truth value.

So, looking at a few more test functions:

```
def test3():
    first = ""
    last = "Smith"
    if first and last:
        print last

def test4():
    first = ""
    last = "Smith"
    print first and last

def test5():
    first = "David"
    last = "Smith"
    if first or last:
        print last

def test6():
    first = "David"
    last = "Smith"
    print first or last

def test7():
    first = "David"
    last = ""
    if first or last:
        print last

def test8():
    first = "David"
    last = ""
    print first or last
```

`test3()` will not print anything.
`test4()` will print `""`.

`test5()` will print `"Smith"`.
`test6()` will print `"David"`.

`test7()` will print `""`.
`test8()` will print `"David"`.

Comment: +1 for a succinct explanation of the short-circuiting. This confused me earlier this week, but I found this [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Non-Programmer%27s_Tutorial_for_Python_3/Boolean_Expressions) link very helpful.

Comment: Edited my response to be responsive to the corrected question.

Answer (score 0):

What, you ask, is the difference between these two snippets?

```
if first and last:
  print last
```

and

```
print first and last
```

In the first case, either the code will print the value of last, or it won't.

In the second case, the code will print the value of `first and last`. If you are used to C, then you might think that the value of `a and b` is a boolean value of either True or False. But you'd be wrong.

`a and b` evaluates `a`; if `a` is truthy, the value of the expression is `b`. If `a` is falsely, the value of the expression is `a`:

```
"David" and "Smith" -> "Smith"
0 and "Smith" -> 0
1 and "Smith" -> "Smith" 
"David" and 0 -> 0
"David" and 1 -> 1
```

Generallly:

- The first prints something sometimes, and doesn't print something other times.

  - The second prints something all of the time.
- The first prints `last`, if it prints anything at all

  - The second prints either `first` or `last`, according to the truthiness of `first`.

Specifically, if `first` is ever `""`, then the 2nd example will print `""` while the 
first won't print anything at all.